# unity make moveable sprite clickable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a player sprite that moves anywhere on the screen clicked. I am trying to make a player info panel popup if the player sprite is clicked.

But unfortunately I only get the player moving a couple of pixels. I have a `Box Collider 2d` added to the sprite and an event trigger set to Pointer Click to run the method `ShowPlayerInfoPanel`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    //Player Movement
    float speed = 2f;
    Vector2 targetPos;

    private Rigidbody2D myRigidbody;
    private Animator myAnim;

    private static bool playerExists;
    public static PlayerController instance;

    public string exitPortal;
    public bool startMoving;

    public float smoothTime = 0.3F;
    private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;

    //Player Info
    public string displayName;
    public string coins;

    //Player Panel display
    public GameObject playerInfoPanel;

    private void Start()
    {

        myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        myAnim = GetComponent<Animator>();

        if(instance == null){
            instance = this;
        } else {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

        DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);

        targetPos = transform.position;

    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            targetPos = (Vector2)Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            startMoving = true;
        }
        if ((Vector2)transform.position != targetPos && startMoving)
        {
            Move();
        } else {
            myAnim.SetBool("PlayerMoving", false);
        }
    }

    void Move()
    {
        Vector2 oldPos = transform.position;
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        //transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, targetPos, ref velocity, smoothTime);

        Vector2 movement = (Vector2)transform.position - oldPos;

        myAnim.SetBool("PlayerMoving", true);

        myAnim.SetFloat("Horizontal", movement.x);
        myAnim.SetFloat("Vertical", movement.y);
    }

    public void ShowPlayerInfoPanel()
    {
        Debug.Log("hi");
        PlayerInfoPanel playerInfo = playerInfoPanel.GetComponent<PlayerInfoPanel>();
        playerInfo.DisplayName.text = displayName;
        playerInfo.Coins.text = coins;
        playerInfoPanel.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a collider on your gameObject you can just use [OnMouseDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html) to detect when the object is clicked.

```
void OnMouseDown()
{
    ShowPlayerInfoPanel();
}
```

Comment: Does isTrigger on the collider need to be true or false?

Comment: Depends what the purpose of your collider is. If you want the sprite to physically react with other colliders you would leave it false. OnMouseDown works with either, however.

Comment: Thank you ryeMoss, exactly what I needed to know.